# kafka connect - s3sink - decode binary decimal values

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Im using debezium to push the data to kafka, and the decimal handling mode is `precise`

Also these lines added into my config(debezium):

```
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
```

But while consuming this with s3-sink connector, the values are still in binary format.

Is there any settings on the sink connector side to decode it?

#### Update:1:

My value converter is aws glue schema registry.

```
"value.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.jsonschema.JsonSchemaConverter"
```

### Update 2:

Debezium config:

```
{
    "name": "mysql-connecter-01",
    "config": {
        "name": "mysql-connecter-01",
        "connecter.class": "io.debezium.connecter.mysql.MySqlconnecter",
        "database.server.id": "1",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "KAFKA_BROKER_NODE_IP:9092",
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "mysql-db01.schema-changes.mysql",
        "database.server.name": "mysql-db01",
        "database.hostname": "MYSQL_IP",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "MYSQL_USER",
        "database.password": "MYSQL_PASS",
        "database.whitelist": "bhuvi",
        "transforms": "unwrap",
        "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
        "transforms.unwrap.add.source.fields": "ts_ms",
        "tombstones.on.delete": false,
        "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "internal.key.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "internal.key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "internal.value.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
        "value.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
        "value.converter.region": "ap-south-1",
        "key.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled": "true",
        "value.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled": "true",
        "key.converter.avroRecordType": "GENERIC_RECORD",
        "value.converter.avroRecordType": "GENERIC_RECORD",
        "key.converter.registry.name": "bhuvi-debezium",
        "value.converter.registry.name": "bhuvi-debezium",
        "snapshot.mode": "initial"
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't in the S3 configuration properties themselves. Handling deserialization would be done in the Converter, if not at the source. Otherwise, `transforms` is what you want. Can you share your full debezium config, though?

Comment: question updated